# Power button not shutting down system on embedded system (i.MX6)

Tags: linux, udev, power-management

I can't get the power button to gracefully shutdown the OS.

My kernel has no configuration options for `acpi`, and `acpid` gives me the following error:

```
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# /usr/sbin/acpid
RTNETLINK1 answers: No such file or directory
acpid: error talking to the kernel via netlink
```

So, my guess is that I have to use `udev`. If I use `udevadm monitor`, no events get raised when I press the power switch.

After digging through the kernel source code (`Linux seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4 3.0.101 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 2 10:49:45 PDT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`) and the imx6 drivers, I finally found something that may help me.

1. I found the power button driver in the OS at `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/imx_seco_pwrb`.

2. Some more info that may be helpful.

```
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/power_button/enable
disable
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/power_button/en_flash
disable
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# ls /sys/bus/platform/drivers/imx_seco_pwrb/
bind    uevent  unbind
```

3. I found `/proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button` which stores the current state of the power button.

```
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button
active
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button
active
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button
active
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button
inactive
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button
inactive
root@seco-uq7-dl-256mbx4:~# cat /proc/ectrl/events/event_state/power_button
inactive
```

My embedded operating system is using sysvinit.

I effectively need the power button to perform a `shutdown -h now`. Any ideas why it isn't currently?